Recurrence-defined polynomial with purely imaginary roots
I am working on a polynomial of arbitrary size, described by the recurrence relation:
$$P_{n+2}=-xP_{n+1}+(n+1)(n+2)P_n, \text{ with } P_0=1, P_1=-x. $$
I observe that for $n$ being odd, $P_n$ has one root at $x=0$ and all other roots are purely imaginary. For $n$ being even, all roots are purely imaginary. It is straightforward to show the one zero root for odd $n$. However, I cannot prove the purely imaginary roots.
What tools are there to prove that the roots of the polynomial are purely imaginary?
I know that Hurwitz determinants are used to show that roots have strictly negative real parts. So I thought maybe they also work for roots with zero real parts.

The exponential generating function of your polynomials is $(d/dz)\exp(x\tan^{-1}(z))/x$.

I was not familiar with generating functions. Could you elaborate on how to obtain it and how to use it to help my problem? @Somos

For generating functions Google is your friend. The coefficients of $P_n$ are in OEIS A008309.
